# Unable to segregate the billing charges of the forwarding rules via labels - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have applied labels to the forwarding rules of global and regional load balancers. But in the cost reports, those labels are not getting applied for cost segregation. SKUs are as below

Cloud Load Balancer Forwarding Rule Additional Global - 1211-928B-AF92

Cloud Load Balancer Forwarding Rule Minimum for Mumbai (asia-south1) - 7386-1FD9-A800

Cloud Load Balancer Forwarding Rule Minimum for Warsaw (europe-central2) - BD24-2324-9CA3

Cloud Load Balancer Forwarding Rule Minimum for Americas (multi-region) - CBE2-3343-9091

Cloud Load Balancer Forwarding Rule Minimum Global - DEE3-C42E-3E4D

Labels are added to the forwarding rules of the load balancers